# passport-jwt token cannot Authorized

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

I cant authorize users, I am trying to console log jwt_payload but I cannot see results. I tried to console log jwt_payload, but I cannot see any logs.

passport.js

```
`const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport){
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,(jwt_payload, done) => {
        console.log(jwt_payload);
        User.getUserById(jwt_payload.sub,(err,user)=> {
            if(err){
                return done(err,false);
            }
            if(user){
                return done(null,user);
            }else {
                return done(null,false)
            }

        });
    }));
}`
```

//user.js

```
router.get('/profile',passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}), (req , res , next) => {
    res.json({user:req.user});
})

Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a request to protected route in your case profile to see jwt_payload output.
If you set up other things correctly it should console log something like this `{ '$__':                                                        { strictMode: true,
selected: {},
getters: {}, 
_id: '59761655e1d793141048e7fc',                                                wasPopulated: false,
activePaths: { paths: [Object], states: [Object], stateNames: [Object] },       pathsToScopes: {}, 
emitter: { domain: null, _events: {}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: 0 } },
isNew: false,
 _doc:
 { __v: 0,
password: '$2a$10$Ek/lrNKHQcRSuQX1H5c2VONOp5InudCI7KeAHkCw96EDkBcY9FEau',      username: 'uzzol',
 _id: '59761655e1d793141048e7fc' },
 '$init': true,
 iat: 1500966142 
}`

I can't see your `getUserById` method but i am pretty sure you will get an error because `jwt_payload.sub` should be undefined here (don't ask me why).You can use `User.findOne({id:jwt_payload.sub},callback)` to find a user. But if you want to get a user by mongoose `findById` method then see what you get from  `jwt_payload`. Now you see the user _id is not under `jwt_payload.sub` but under `jwt_payload._doc._id`. so your code should be something like this 
`User.findById({_id:jwt_payload._doc._id},callback);`

please check my git repository for a working version: https://github.com/uzzol101/auth_app/tree/master

Comment: Thanks, I've already solve it i haven't been able to add space on 
                   ` token: 'JWT '+token`

Comment: try this `token: 'JWT '+token`. notice an extra space after JWT.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using,

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
```

send Authorization header with **Bearer + your genarated token** instead **JWT + your genarated token**